# Scale image in flash to match size defined in html

Tags: flash, cs3

I have a flash movie that loads images dynamically from an xml file.  I want to re-use this .swf file on different pages, however the images on page1 are all 400 x 200 and the images on page2 are all 745 x 422.  When i try to reuse this on another page, the loaded images are shrunken (resized) - i would like them to match whats defined in the width/height, but they get scaled depending on how the stage is scaled.

im using a loader (AS3) for the image that places them on a container(sprite)

```
slideLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlSlideshow..image[intCurrentSlide].@src));
```

I have tried making the stage various sizes to start, but i would really like it to be irrelavant if possible - ie: 50 x 50.  Then in html the width/height would be set to the width/height of the images being loaded.

Im not a flash wizard so please forgive me if im not clear, i'll try to give more insight if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things... firstly you'll need to specify your app not to scale. (AS3 code)

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Then once your image is loaded (add a listener to the slideLoader object), execute a javascript function using flash's ExternalInterface class.

```
ExternalInterface.call('resizeFlashMovie', slideLoader.width, slideLoader.height);
```

And your javascript function would be something like this:

```
function resizeFlashMovie(width, height) {
    var flash = document.getElementById('yourFlashMovieId');
    flash.style.width = width+'px';
    flash.style.height = height+'px';
}
```

Comment: wow thank you very much, i would have never figured that out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize I don't have the code at hand, but I know you have the option to set a no-resize on the canvas at startup.

Ideally, you can pass in the height/width via the attributes of the embed tag, have a no resize on the canvas and use the passed in dimensions to set your image dimenions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is it:

```
fscommand("allowscale","false");
```

Comment: I tried to add that at the class definition and also on the function that is called when the load event occurs - in both instances it doesnt show anything, but acts like i clicked on the image (have click event attached) - am i doing something wrong?  Where should fscommand be used? - Thank you :-)